# Need help in Writing custom attribute in MVC

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-mvc

I have to write custom attribute to check dependent property using MVC pattern.  I am using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations for checking required fields.
My WPF application contains listview control.  All my properties written in modal class get filled in listview when view is loaded first time.
I am providing functionality where user can include/exclude new property in listview.  However I don't want to allow user to exclude those property on which other properties are dependent.

For example, If securitynumber property depends on employeename property. While excluding employeename, I want to display validation message that "securitynumber depends on employeename, so can't exclude employeename"

I need help in writing and using  custom attribute for e.g

```
[Dependencyon("Employeename")]
public object securitynumber { get ;set ;}
```

and want to get value of "Dependencyon" wherever I needed.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how to write custom attributes at all? If not, start by looking at a tutorial on how to write custom attributes.

Comment: I am trying to write a class which is derived from ValidationAttribute class.Also trying to override IsValid method, but no success.I am new to MVC and have to finish this validation ASAP due to time constraint.

Comment: What hasn't been successful about it?  Try creating a validator for CustomValidationAttribute.  It may prove the simplest for you.

Answer (score 2):

You have three options:

A) You can use the CustomValidationAttribute and supply a custom built validator.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute.validatortype(v=vs.95).aspx

B) You can create a class that inherits from ValidationAttribute.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668224.aspx

C) If you only want to do this on the MVC Action you can Create an ActionFilterAttribute as per gordatron's response.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking to create a custom filter.. Its been a while but from memory I think it would be something like:

```
public class Dependencyon : ActionFilterAttribute {

    string field;

    public Dependencyon (string field){
        this.field = field;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //check whether field is populated and redirect if not?    
    }
}
```

here is a starter on ActionFilters:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

(I cannot remember details on constructor params for these so i may be way off.. sorry but i guess it wont take long to try)

Comment: Thanks All for helping me.I have written custom attribute .

Comment: @user184842 which kind of attribute.. if you did something different to the answers posted here then post what you did and mark it as an answer.